# Partial retry of parallel states in a step function state machine

Tags: aws-step-functions

In a parallel state with multiple task branches, if some of them, maybe 1 or 2 branches but not all, fail all their own retry attempts, how do you programmatically retry the state machine execution without triggering retries of other branches, given that you can't retry the failed task branch manually? Is there a design pattern for this kind of situation?

Workflow is like: `Start -> Parallel (Branch A, B, C, D, E) -> Report -> End`

Let's say that B and D failed but other succeeded.

I wanted to partial retry the workflow like

`Start -> Parallel (Branch B, D) -> Report -> End`

Comment: Is there substantial work being done before and/or after the Parallel State?  In other words, is the Parallel State at the beginning, middle, or end of the SM?

Comment: @fedonev There's work after the parallel. It's like Start -> Parallel (multiple branches) -> Report -> End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: It's tricky because we have to do our own error handling and retry limiting.

1. Use as `Pass` state at the head of each branch to add a branch identifier to the branch payload. A `Lambda Task` evaluates whether a branch's tasks need doing. Must handle the first (raw payload) and subsequent iterations (payload decorated with an array of failed branches e.g. `wantsRetryBranch: [branch identifiers]` that will be added in #3). A `Choice` determines whether the branch should proceed based on the Lambda's output. The `Choice` should evaluate to true for new executions and for retries with a branch error.
2. All branches must return success.<sup>*</sup> If an error occurs within a branch, we must catch it and return some indication of error in the return payload, e.g. `{status: "fail", error: <error-detail>}`
3. Following the `Parallel` State, a `Lambda Task` evaluates the output array for errors. A "Retry?" `Choice` state follows. Loop back to #1 if a branch has errors and retry counter has not reached its limit. Otherwise, execution ends in `Success` or `Fail` depending on the presence or absence of errors.

##### States Outline

```sh
Parallel
  Identify [Pass] # a pass task that labels the branch with an ID  (A, B, C, D)
  CheckShouldDo [Lambda] # a lambda task return true if branch should run - if wantsRetryBranch array is missing or has branch ID
  DoBranch? [Choice] # evaluate previous step's outupt proceed if true, skip to empty pass task if false
    Skip [Pass] # if shouldDo === false, bypass the tasks
    Tasks # do the actual work; catch errors, write output to tasks key - task.taskName.status should be `success` or `fail`

CheckShouldRetry [Lambda] # evaluate array coming from parallel - look for task errors and whether retry limit is reached
# (continue) returns a payload map consistent with the initial event or full history; make sure to increment retry limits
Retry? [Choice] # evaluate the map from the previous step - if payload-like, go loop back to to Parallel; or end with success or fail

Success # all branches passed
Fail # if after retries, wantsRetryBranch array is not empty
```

##### A Picture Is Worth 1000 Words

[image: Parallel Partial Retry State Machine]

---

* A failure of any `Parallel` branches [stops all branches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html). We lose visibility of which branches succeeded despite the error. Because of this, we must keep track of branch success-failure ourselves, without Step Functions' built in error-handling.